# cppcheck reporting false positives

Tags: static-code-analysis, cppcheck

I am running cppcheck on my project and am getting reports of unused Functions that ARE definitely used (project wont compile if I remove them).
Are there any known reasons why this might happen ? or how I can stop the false reports

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In case this error is still present in the latest version of cppcheck, could you please create a minimal example that demonstrates the issue. Having such a test case, the cppcheck developers can fix the issue. I also recommend that you report such issues to cppcheck bugtracker [here](http://trac.cppcheck.net/).

Answer (score 0):

One reason is that you did not configure as expected Cppcheck, you have to specify the include paths and defines,  you can also use [CppDepend](http://www.cppdepend.com) which integrate now cppcheck and did all the configuration staf from the projects you analyse, and also report all methods not used.